# Hardware filter for a rotary encoder using a resistor between pullup resistor and debouncing capacitor?

Tags: encoder, rotary, debouncing

[image]

I want to implement a debouncing filter for this rotary encoder. I understand the use of the pull up resistor (avoid floating state) and the capacitor (debounce the mechanical switch).
However, I can't see why is included in this circuit a resistor between the pull up resistor and the capacitor. Only thing I can think of is a voltage divider, which doesn't sound good since this creates Vdd/2 and the VIH of my MCU is 0.75·Vcc...

Does anyone know why would they include this resistor? Maybe the input is not 5V tolerant? Or am I missing something? Transient response analysis might be useful for this?

Comment: "*Only thing I can think of is a voltage divider, which doesn't sound good since this creates Vdd/2*". The path has a capacitor also. So the voltage divider us not dividing perfect half. In fact, for low frequency, the capacitor impedance is expected to be much larger than the resistors and so, you will get voltage very close to `Vdd`.

Comment: it is generally easier to filter in software and leave the RC filter for ESD protection.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your switches upon closing to handle the very high current that the capacitor can source there – that can quickly wear them out.

Therefore, current limiting needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you Marcus! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to use the same encoder, or at least the drawing is exactly the same, and it's actually quite hard to debounce them, even with the filter.

The resistor creates an RC filter.

The best I had, is to use the filter as on the schematic, then use the MCU pin interrupt to start a timer that will sample both pin about 10 times to define the actual direction of rotation, and even with all that it's not always accurate depending on the speed the knob is turned.

Comment: what's the maximum switching speed you need to work with? Because you're right, that *is* an RC filter, and you've got some freedom in designing it!

Comment: Switching speed is not really the issue, it's the debounce as the phase of both switch indicate the direction. The phasing delta is a few ms (10-20ms if I recall) with bouncing all over the place, especially if turned fast. I think this encoder is of poor quality and I've seen encoder with 3 output which probably are better. @MarcusMüller

Comment: yeah, point is, if you know your individual switch is not switching faster than say 100 Hz, then a 200 Hz cutoff frequency works well; the waveform coming out of that at full speed will look more like a sine than a square wave, sure, but your MCU doesn't care (unlike about the bounces)

Comment: If worst case scenario is a 50 Hz cutoff frequency (bounces of 10 ms), then wouldn't it be wise to use a 5 Hz cutoff frequency (1 decade of distance)? Only problem is encoder would be pretty slow. Maybe a 25 Hz cutoff frequency would work. Anyways, if the problem is the encoders quality, do you recommend a non-contact type of encoder instead?

Comment: @user3138306 non-contact, if it exist would be nice, please let me know if you find such part.